# How to display svg markers that contain links to other svgs in HERE maps?

Tags: svg, here-api

I am trying to display svg markers using the HERE Javascript API.  I have followed the [documentation](https://developer.here.com/api-explorer/maps-js/markers/map-with-svg-graphic-markers), however my twist is that my svg contains links to other svgs.  The reason for this is that I would like to display markers that have the same pin shape, but a different icon in the centre of the pin.  As the icons will also be used in other places on my website, it makes sense to save the svgs separately so they only need updating in one place.

I can get standard svgs to display as markers, but when I try and nest the svgs, no marker is displayed on the map.

This is my code so far:

pin.svg - This is the basic pin shape that all markers will use

```
<svg
   xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
   xmlns:cc="http://creativecommons.org/ns#"
   xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
   xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   version="1.1"
   width="46.093765"
   height="63.352634">
  <g
     transform="translate(-8.9327811,-0.45623957)"
     id="layer1">
    <path
       d="M 22.15625,0 A 21.544797,22.053723 0 0 0 0,22.0625 21.544797,22.053723 0 0 0 10.40625,40.9375 c 1.062265,1.795846 11.125,19.40625 11.125,19.40625 l 12.125,-20.0625 A 21.544797,22.053723 0 0 0 43.09375,22.0625 21.544797,22.053723 0 0 0 22.15625,0 z"
       transform="translate(10.432788,1.9651232)"
       id="path5014"
       style="fill:#cccccc;fill-opacity:1;stroke:#6e6e6e;stroke-width:2;stroke-miterlimit:4;stroke-opacity:1;stroke-dasharray:none" />
    <path
       d="m 50.723066,23.370655 a 17.218699,16.540131 0 1 1 -34.437397,0 17.218699,16.540131 0 1 1 34.437397,0 z"
       transform="matrix(0.94189641,0,0,1.0010512,0.4199413,0.48436132)"
       id="path5019"
       style="fill:#ffffff;fill-opacity:1;stroke:none" />
  </g>
</svg>
```

here-example.svg - This is the example from the HERE site.  I am using it as an icon that gets placed inside the pin

```
<svg width="24" height="24" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <rect stroke="black" fill="red" x="1" y="1" width="22" height="22" />
    <text x="12" y="18" font-size="12pt" font-family="Arial" font-weight="bold" text-anchor="middle" fill="yellow">
    C
    </text>
</svg>
```

pin-with-icon.svg - This is my nested svg - it pulls in the pin and the icon and overlaps them

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">

    <image x="20" y="20" width="300" height="80" xlink:href="pin.svg" />
    <image x="120" y="32" width="100" height="30" xlink:href="here-example.svg" />
</svg>
```

index.html - This is where the HERE map is used and I try and display the markers.  It makes heavy use of the HERE developer documentation.  Replace `<App_ID>` and `<App_Code>` with the HERE credentials.  In this page I also try and load the problematic svg into a div to prove that it works.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, width=device-width" />
    <script src="http://js.api.here.com/v3/3.0/mapsjs-core.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script src="http://js.api.here.com/v3/3.0/mapsjs-service.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script src="http://js.api.here.com/v3/3.0/mapsjs-ui.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script src="http://js.api.here.com/v3/3.0/mapsjs-mapevents.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://js.api.here.com/v3/3.0/mapsjs-ui.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div style="width: 640px; height: 480px" id="mapContainer"></div>

    <!-- Display the svg just to prove that the loads correctly -->
    <div id="svgPin"></div>

    <script>
      // Initialize the platform object:
      var platform = new H.service.Platform({
        'app_id': '<App_ID>',
        'app_code': '<App_Code>'
      });

      // Obtain the default map types from the platform object
      var maptypes = platform.createDefaultLayers();

      // Instantiate (and display) a map object:
      var map = new H.Map(
        document.getElementById('mapContainer'),
        maptypes.normal.map,
        {
          zoom: 6,
          center: { lng: 13.4, lat: 52.51 }
        });

        // MapEvents enables the event system
        // Behavior implements default interactions for pan/zoom (also on mobile touch environments)
        var behavior = new H.mapevents.Behavior(new H.mapevents.MapEvents(map));

        // Example with svg pins not showing (svg contains links to other svgs)
        var svgMarkupRetrieval = $.get('pin-with-icon.svg', function (svg) {

            // Just to prove that the svg is loaded correctly
            $('#svgPin').html(svg);

            var icon = new H.map.Icon(svg);

            // Add the first marker
            var marker1 = new H.map.Marker({ lat: 52.4, lng: 13.3 },
                { icon: icon });

            map.addObject(marker1);

            // Add the second marker.
            var marker2 = new H.map.Marker({ lat: 51.45, lng: 13.3 },
                { icon: icon });

            map.addObject(marker2);
        }, 'text');


        // Example with svg pins showing (from HERE developer guide)
        var svgMarkupRetrieval = $.get('here-example.svg', function (svg) {
            var icon = new H.map.Icon(svg);

            // Add the first marker
            var marker3 = new H.map.Marker({ lat: 50.4, lng: 13.3 },
                { icon: icon });

            map.addObject(marker3);

            // Add the second marker.
            var marker4 = new H.map.Marker({ lat: 49.45, lng: 13.3 },
                { icon: icon });

            map.addObject(marker4);
        }, 'text');
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

To use the code, create each file with the name I specify and put them in a folder in IIS.  `index.html` has to be run through IIS, otherwise a cross origin request error occurs.

The pin-with-icon.svg loads separately (I load it under the map), as do the standard svg markers.  But I cannot see why the markers I create using pin-with-icon.svg do not show on the map.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: IIRC, the HERE Maps API supports SVG tiny - you should check to see if nesting is supported. As a quick-n-dirty hack you could place TWO markers over the same point and use the zOrder attribute to make your icon appear in front.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `H.map.DomMarker` and `H.map.DomIcon`

Comment: Thank you, that makes the marker appear.  However when I zoom the map (either with the mouse scroll wheel or using the map's own zoom controls), the icons do not stay at their lat/long position.  Instead they end up halfway around the world.  Any ideas?

Comment: use the `left`/`top`-style of `pin-with-icon.svg` to anchor the combined pin at the correct position(by default it's the top-left corner, but with the given pin.svg it should be the bottom-center)